# Blockchain outbound oracle code sample in solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink

Being new to Ethereum blockchain, when learning the chainlink/oracles, have found few examples for the inbound oracles. for example getting price of bitcoin or diesel price etc from price feeds or by calling API.
I could not find any example code for the outbound oracle in solidity even after searching on Internet for long hours.

Would appreciate any guidance to get some sample code to practice the outbound oracle.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand is that you are looking for example code to create an outbound oracle in Solidity,here is an example:

```
contract Chainlink is usingOraclize {
    string public EURUSD;
    function updatePrice() public payable {
        if (oraclizegetPrice("URL") > this.balance) { 
            //Handle out of funds error 
        } else {
            oraclizequery("URL", "json(http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD).rates.USD");
        }
    }
    function _callback(bytes32 myid, string result) public {
        require(msg.sender == oraclizecbAddress());
        EURUSD = result;
    }
}
```

if you want to achieve certain condition is met in solidity code and send this information through an outbound oracle to another smart contract or on any other application, you can achieve that by using the Solidity language's event system, this event system will help you to send data to external service.

here is an example:

```
  contract DummyContract {
    event LogSent(bytes32 data);
    function sendData(address otherContractAddress, bytes32 data) public {
        // execute functions when certain conditions are met
        if (someCondition) {
            someFunction();
        }

    emit LogSent(data);
    // call other contract
    otherContractAddress.call(data);

    // call outbound oracle
    Oracle.sendData(data);
}


}
```

Comment: Thank you Mado for the reply.  The above example provided seems to get detail from outside world and is giving the smart contract . I was trying to find solidity code where a certain condition is met in solidity code and it will send this information through an outbound oracle to another smart contract or on any other application.

Comment: what you want is something like if 1 == 1 then send this data to another contractAddress,  am i right ?

Comment: Yes, thats right. Below is one of the definitions i was reading for the outbound oracle.
https://learn.bybit.com/blockchain/what-are-blockchain-oracles/
"Outbound Oracles
Outbound oracles function in the opposite manner. Instead of bringing external data to the blockchain, they take blockchain data and send it to another system. Depending on the way the oracle is set up, you can even instruct other systems (such as a banking network) to perform a task based on information from the blockchain"

Comment: that's actually fun to do, please check my answer again i edited and added new answer. hopefully that's what you looking for!, after i went through the solidity docs, there is a feature called event system that's allows you to perform this task.